# split string into substrings that start with prefixes

Tags: c#, split

I'm looking to split a string into substrings and each of the substrings starts and ends with [[ ]]

e.g.

I've only used a dash and colon as examples - it could be anything including space or no space. I'm just looking to get each of the substrings including the square brackets.

```
string mystring = "[[string 1]] - [[string 2]] : [[string 3]]"
```

Can I split this into

```
[[string 1]]
[[string 2]]
[[string 3]]
```

A list will do...

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Use a regular expression to tokenize the input

Comment: A regular expression is the way to go, there's an example on the String.Split msdn about this very issue (titled "Alternatives to String.Split").
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks

Comment: I'm not going to throw this down as an answer, but why not split on `[[` and parse out anything before/after it?  This might be a different way of approaching it if you're not too fond on regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = "[[string 1]] - [[string 2]] : [[string 3]]";
var parts = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[\[.+?\]\]").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value)
                 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "[[string 1]][[string 2]][[string 3]]";
input = input.Replace("][","]-[");
List<string> result = input.split('-').ToList();
```

If you want an array, replace the last line with:

```
string[] result = input.split('-');
```